# AngularJS - any way to export xls with dynamic content?

Tags: angularjs, excel

I'm investigating for a client feature and I didn't reach the right answer.

This is quite simple : the user edits a full table with datas ( numbers ), chooses which cells receive the sum of which cells and export it.

In Angular we can keep the calculation and hide it to show the result. But what I would like to do is to keep the calculation active when exporting on xls.

For ex.

```
 Cell1 = 25 Cell2 = 45
 Cell3 = 70 (Sum(Cell1,Cell2));
```

In the XLS file It should keep the Sum() function instead of a "flat" 70.

Am I clear enough ? Does someone know a library that can do this ? or the best process to succeed in this feature ?

Answer (score 1):

Excel files are essentially XML Documents.

However building Excel using plain XML is a crazy job...

You can try using the library (ClosedXML) if you are using .NET. https://closedxml.codeplex.com/

It makes much easir to build Excel files.

```
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.AddWorksheet("Sheet1");
ws.Cell("A1").SetValue(1).CellBelow().SetValue(1);
ws.Cell("B1").SetValue(1).CellBelow().SetValue(1);

ws.Cell("C1").FormulaA1 = "\"The total value is: \" & SUM(A1:B2)";

var r = ws.Cell("C1").Value;
Assert.AreEqual("The total value is: 4", r.ToString());

// It also works if you use: ws.Cell("C1").GetString()
```